# Reference Multiple files in the same schema.ini

Tags: oledb

I have several text files with tab delimited data. I want to have a single ini file for all of them.

Tried this:

```
[*.txt]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=TabDelimited
```

But that did not work.

The files are named:

- one.txt
- two.txt
- etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this.

[one.txt]

Format=tabdelimited

[two.txt]

Format=tabdelimited

[three.txt]

Format=tabdelimited

Hope it works.

Regards.

Comment: I was hoping for more. But if every filename is listed it works.